# $ f(x) = \int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt $ , for all $ x \gt 0 $. Then, f(x) is greater than

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $ f(x) = \int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt $ for all  $ x \gt 0 $.
>
> Then for all $ x \gt 0 $,
>
> a.)  $x e^{-x^2} \lt f(x) $
>
> b.) $x \lt f(x) $
>
> c.) $1 \lt f(x) $
>
> d.) none of the statements is true.

My approach:

$$e^{-t^2} \lt 1  \quad \forall \quad t>0 $$
$ \qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad  $  Integrate on both sides

$$ \int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt \lt \int_{0}^x  dt  \quad \forall \quad x>0 $$
$$ \int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt \lt x  $$
i.e, $$ f(x) \lt x  $$
So, option b is not correct.
And also f(x) is an increasing function. How to proceed further?

Comment: To rule out option c you could evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}/2<1$ because of the Gaussian Integral.

Comment: Hint: $e^{-t^2}\geq e^{-x^2},\forall t~{\rm with~}0\leq t\leq x$

Comment: You've proved $f(1/2) < 1/2$ so c cannot be true

Comment: @Pythagoras i integrated after your hint and i get $\int_{0}^x e^{-t^2} dt \ge x e^{-x^2}$. This is correct but what about equaity?

Comment: For some $0<t<x$, $e^{-t^2}>e^{-x^2}$, so the inequality is strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rule out option c you could evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\sqrt{\pi}/2<1$ because of the Gaussian Integral.

Now for option a let $g(x)=xe^{-x^2}$. Since g(0)=0 we know that

$$
g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g'(t)dt = \int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt- \int_{0}^{x}2t^2 e^{-t^2}dt < f(x)
$$

So option a is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $M$ and $L$ are the maximum and minimum value of some function $g$ in any given interval $[a,b]$ and provided the function is continuous and integrable in the domain then we have :
$$ L\cdot (b-a) \leq \int \limits_{a}^b g(t) \,dt \leq M\cdot (b-a)$$
As $e^{-t^2}$ is decreasing therefore the maxima is obtained at $t=0$ and minima is obtained at $t=x$ in the interval $[0,x]$ therefore we have :
$$e^{-x^2}\cdot (x-0)\leq \int \limits_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} \,dt \leq 1\cdot (x-0)$$
Henceforth ,
$$xe^{-x^2}\leq \int \limits_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} \,dt \leq x$$
Therefore option $(a)$ is correct.

Comment: I know this concept but still missed it. Thank you for your solution.